# Issues on using synchronized method

Tags: java, synchronization

I am trying to understand synchronization, but while it tried to implement it,I am getting an ambiguous result, while trying to implement synchronized, Have a look at it.

By obesrving the output, it is clear that two threads are able to access the synchronized block simultaneously.  Guide me where am I Going wrong.

Output:

```
Display class show method called by- Thread-0
Display class show method called by- Thread-0
Display class show method called by- Thread-0
Display class show method called by- Thread-0
Display class show method called by- Thread-0
Display class show method called by- Thread-0
Display class show method called by- Thread-0
Display class show method called by- Thread-1
Display class show method called by- Thread-1
Display class show method called by- Thread-1
Display class show method called by- Thread-1
Display class show method called by- Thread-1
Display class show method called by- Thread-1
Display class show method called by- Thread-1
Display class show method called by- Thread-1
Display class show method called by- Thread-1
Display class show method called by- Thread-1
Display class show method called by- Thread-0
Display class show method called by- Thread-0
Display class show method called by- Thread-0
```

Program:

```
package com.StackOverFlow.Doubts3;

public class Dbts5 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Display d1= new Display();
    MyThreads th1= new MyThreads(d1, "Thread1");

    th1.start();

    MyThreads th2= new MyThreads(d1, "Thread2");

    th2.start();




}
}

class MyThreads extends Thread{


Display d;
String name;


@Override
public void run() {
    super.run();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        d.show();   
    }



}

public MyThreads() {}

MyThreads(Display d, String name){
    this.d=d;
    this.name=name;
}


}

class Display{

synchronized void show(){
    System.out.println("Display class show method called by- "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    try {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(300);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

(Edited)
Expected output:

```
Display class show method called by- Thread-0
Display class show method called by- Thread-0
Display class show method called by- Thread-0
.
.
.
Display class show method called by- Thread-1
Display class show method called by- Thread-1
Display class show method called by- Thread-1
```

Comment: I do not see how the output shows that threads "access the synchronized block simultaneously". In fact, since you only output one line in the `show()` method, there is no way to decide what's happening inside `show()`, apart from the fact that it has been executed.

Comment: Why do you think they are accessing it simultaneously? One thread prints out the message, exits the function, then another one comes in ...

Comment: What did yoi expect to happen?

Comment: @meskobalazs :I have edited and put my expected result.

Comment: @Arkadiy  Look at the program closely, Its not one thread accessing the show method printing out the line and coming out. cause, in the run method of MyThread, there is a loop and this loop belong to only one thread(th1). so until that thread is executed completely the other thread(th2) should not get a chance right?

Comment: Why downvote? OP asks "Guide me where am I going wrong". It is fully legitimate to ask a question when you do not understand what is going on.

Comment: @Dima Look at the program closely, Its not one thread accessing the show method printing out the line and coming out. cause, in the run method of MyThread, there is a loop and this loop belong to only one thread(th1). so until that thread is executed completely the other thread(th2) should not get a chance right?

Comment: The effect of `synchronized` is as follows: two threads cannot be executing the synchronized region at the same time. Your output shows that t0, then t1, then t0 again execute the synchronized region - sequentially. It does not show that both t1 and t0 are in the synchronized region at th same time.

Comment: @user2900314 loop is not synchronized, only this `show` method is, so as soon as one thread exits it, the other one may enter even if the first one is not done with the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By obesrving the output, it is clear that two threads are able to access the synchronized block simultaneously.

No, there's absolutely no evidence of that. Let's consider the following output:

```
Display class show method called by- Thread-0
Display class show method called by- Thread-1
```

Here:

- `Thread-0` calls `show()`, enters the `synchronized` block, prints out the message, *exits from `show()`* (leaving the `synchronized` block).
- `Thread-1` calls `show()`, enters the `synchronized` block, prints out the message, *exits from `show()`* (leaving the `synchronized` block).

and so on.

If you want to see the threads blocking each other, put `synchronized` around the loop:

```
synchronized(d) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        d.show();   
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using the for loop inside the run method of MyThread, so I was expecting that only one gets to use the synchronized block. Why is this wrong.I might sound silly but I wanted to know why I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your synchronized block is not accessed concurrently.

What you observe is:

- Thread-0 gets in and out 7 times
- Thread-1 gets in and out 10 times
- Thread-0 gets in and out 3 times

If you add some trace, you will see better that `show` is never entered twice before exiting:

```
synchronized void show(){
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " In");
    // do show
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Out");
}
```

And you will see:

```
Thread-0 In
Display class show method called by- Thread-0
Thread-0 Out
// ...
Thread-1 In
Display class show method called by- Thread-1
Thread-1 Out
// ...
Thread-0 In
Display class show method called by- Thread-0
Thread-0 Out
```

---

If you want the threads to call `show` n times before releasing the lock, then you should use `synchronized` around the `for-loop`:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    showSeveralTimes(10);
}
```

And in `Display`:

```
synchronized void showSeveralTimes(int n) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i) {
        show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from an [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html):

> - First, it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the same object to interleave. When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first thread is done with the object.
> - Second, when a synchronized method exits, it automatically establishes a happens-before relationship with any subsequent invocation of a synchronized method for the same object. This guarantees that changes to the state of the object are visible to all threads.

So `Thread-n` runs, returns, `Thread-n` runs, returns, ad infinitum (or 10 in this case)